# ASP.NET 6 authentication (Identity) files location

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I created a ASP.NET 6 MVC application with authentication as individual accounts. But in `Areas/Identity` folder only have on folder `Pages`. It contains `_ViewStart.cshtml`. No any other files or folders in `Areas/Identity` folder. App works fine with authentication system. How do I find the files related to authentication (Identity) ?

[Screenshot of Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BN94Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check the file ***Views/Shared***, you can see the ***_LoginPartial.cshtml***
I hope you can fix your issue with this, if not, please let me know.
Great day.

Comment: Can I customize `Identity` only using that `partial` ? From where I can find `Controllers` of `identity` ?

Answer (score 0):

> The good news is that in ASP.NET Core 2.1 we can now ship Razor UI in reusable class libraries. We are using this feature to provide the entire identity UI as a prebuilt package

Microsoft moves them to a prebuilt package to reduce ~50 files that add to your project

You can find the reason in this blog
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnetcore-2-1-identity-ui/